# UtteranceProgressListener (TTS) not working or not being called (Android 4.4.2)

Tags: java, android, listener, text-to-speech

Since 2 days I'm trying to get an UtteranceProgressListener to work. I've been trying a lot of codes from Stackoverflow and some other sites - nothing worked for me. Here is my current code:

This is my method for activating text-to-speech. It's called in onCreate.

```
private void activateTTS() {
    tts=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                int result=tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
                if (result==TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA ||
                        result==TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                }
                tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
                    @Override 
                    public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
                        if (utteranceId == "myId") {
                            //[...] all my code that is not being called
                            //when speaking is finished
                        }
                    } 

                    @Override 
                    public void onError(String utteranceId) {
                    } 

                    @Override 
                    public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
                    } 
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I know that there is the need of a HashMap with utteranceId to identify the utterance. Here my code (just a part of a method):

```
params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "myId");
tts.speak(myString, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, params);
```

My important variables (for tts and the HashMap) are:

```
private static TextToSpeech tts;
private HashMap<String, String> params;
```

Any code is a part of my class "TTSPlayer" that extends MainActivity but does not implement anything:

```
public class TTSPlayer extends MainActivity {
//[all my code]
}
```

**Edit:** Here is my manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.saschaha.readit"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:name="com.saschaha.readit.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.saschaha.readit.TTSPlayer"
        android:label="@string/ReadIt" >
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

The tts is working fine (text is beeing spoken) but UtteranceProgressListener does not work (my code is not being called). I don't know why. Any help?
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

The error is with the String comparison

```
if (utteranceId == "myId")
```

Change it to

```
if ("myId".equals(utteranceId))
```

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't working too. Now I set my code into a runnable and that works for me (because I wanted to make some UI changes). But now there is a new problem: After rotation screen, the UI changes take no effect anymore. I think, I will just rewrite my whole class and maybe get it to work. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @saschaha , yes , exactly as you said about UI changes. The odd and a important  thing  here s it doesnt trigger any error. Just  interrupts method work and returns.